# Error 400: Request[/editRecordsAction] does not contain handler parameter named

Tags: java, http, struts

I'm creating a struts app and I am using an dispatch action. This was working a while ago and now has stopped and is holding me up. here is the the action mapping and the action request for one page. It give mes an error on all the pages that use the dispatch action. I get these errors.

Error 400: Request[/editRecordsAction] does not contain handler parameter named

console error

[7/28/10 8:28:38:658 CDT] 0000001d DispatchActio E org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction unspecified Request[/editRecordsAction] does not contain handler parameter named

```
<action name="editRecords" path="/editRecordsAction"  type="ccreports.actions.editRecordsAction"
parameter="parameter">
<forward name="editRepViewFwd" path="jsps/RepViewEdit.jsp"></forward>
<forward name="editSupViewFwd" path="jsps/SupViewEdit.jsp"></forward>
<forward name="noViewActionFwd" path="jsps/NoViewSelect.jsp"></forward>
<forward name="delRepFwd" path="jsps/RepViewEdit.jsp"></forward>
<forward name="delSupFwd" path="jsps/SupViewEdit.jsp"></forward>
<forward name="delNoFwd" path="jsps/NoViewSelect.jsp"></forward>
</action>

<html:form action="/editRecordsAction?parameter=editSupViewAction">
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is found here"

```
<html:form action="/editRecordsAction?parameter=editSupViewAction">
```

You forgot to add the **.do** (or whatever servlet mapping you have) to your action.

Here's the solution:

```
<html:form action="/editRecordsAction.do?parameter=editSupViewAction">
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 400: Request[/editRecordsAction] does not contain handler parameter named

this error message lets me think the link should have looked like:

/editRecordsAction.do?parameter=OneOfYourForwardNames

dispatch actions require a httprequest parameter be passed in, and the name of the required parameter is the name you type in your struts mapping. in your case 'parameter'.  the form's action is not giving editRecordsAction what it needs is my best guess...

hope this helps,